# Tkinter MessageBox text on custom Button

Tags: python, tkinter

On windows, `PredefinedType` of `Tkinter.Messagebox` (for exemple retrycancel) are shown in the Windows default language (retry/cancel if en_US, Recommencer/Annuler if fr_FR, and so on).

Is there a way to retrieve those Windows label in order to correctly initialize a custom Button with the respective language translation.

`Tkinter.Button(text=????)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to retrieve the translated strings through the tcl interpreter:

```
import tkinter as tk

def translate(text):
    return root.tk.eval("namespace eval ::tk {::msgcat::mc %s}" % text)


root = tk.Tk()
tk.Button(root, text=translate("retry")).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Tcl uses the package `msgcat` for the internationalization so `::msgcat::mc string` returns the translation for `string` in the current locale. The `namespace eval` is needed to access the translations loaded for the `tk` package.